# Getting an ArrayList from Firestore and the document name

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new on Google Firebase and I'm trying to learn something about it.
I'm doing an Android app where you can create a group of person and set the title of the group..then, in the "group page", you can see all your group in a listview.
The structure of my firestore db is something like this:

**users** --> **email(document)** ---> **Group(collection)** --> **GroupName(Document)** and the group name document contains the partecipants arrayList (partecipant 0 : Name1, partecipant1: name2 etc).

I would like to retrieve the document id(which is the group title) and the arrayList of partecipants, but I don't know of to use the for each in the code...

This is my code:

```
public void load_list_view(){

    String email = getEmail();
    final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(email).collection("Group").document();

    docRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {


                        titleArray.add(documentSnapshot.getId());
                        titleString = documentSnapshot.getId();

                        partecipantsArray.add(documentSnapshot.getString("partecipant"));
                        num_partecipants =  partecipantsArray.size();
                        numArray.add(num_partecipants);
                        trash = R.drawable.trash_icon;
                        firstChar = Character.toString(titleString.charAt(0));
                        firstCharArray.add(firstChar);
                        customAdapter = new GroupAdapter(GroupActivity.this, firstCharArray, titleArray, numArray, trash);
                        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);


                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(GroupActivity.this, e.getStackTrace().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

}
```

with `titleArray.add(documentSnapshot.getId());` it retrieve a random ID and I can't understand why.

I haven't found enough documentation on Internet about `Arraylist` and firestore.

Comment: Please add your database structure to see it more clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First of all**, to get all the documents in a collection you should write your code differently as shown in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection).

```
db.collection("cities")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

---

**Secondly**, if you are retrieving an ArrayList you should use `(ArrayList<String>) documentSnapshot.get("key")` instead of `documentSnapshot.getString("key")`.

---

**Thirdly**, you are getting random Id because with this line of code (mentioned below) firebase is generating a new document reference with a random id. [Reference Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document).

```
    final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(email).collection("Group").document();
```

---

For your help, I have tweaked your code and you can try this code and check if it's working or not.

```
public void load_list_view() {

        String email = getEmail();
        final DocumentReference docRef = firestore.collection("users").document(email);

        docRef.collection("Group")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                            //Extracting Group name from each document

                            titleString = document.getId();
                            titleArray.add(titleString);

                            //Extracting participants ArrayList from each document

                            partecipantsArray.add((ArrayList<String>) document.get("participant"));
                            numArray.add(num_partecipants);
                            firstChar = Character.toString(titleString.charAt(0));
                            firstCharArray.add(firstChar);

                        }

                        num_partecipants = partecipantsArray.size();
                        numArray.add(num_partecipants);
                        trash = R.drawable.trash_icon;
                        firstChar = Character.toString(titleString.charAt(0));
                        firstCharArray.add(firstChar);
                        customAdapter = new GroupAdapter(GroupActivity.this, firstCharArray, titleArray, numArray, trash);
                        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        //HANDLE EXCEPTION
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For People doing in kotlin you can do the following things to get an arraylist from FireStore

1. First get the ArrayList as String
2. Remove the char at first and last Index
3. Split the String at each ','
4. Convert the list to an Array List

Here is the Code

```
ArrayList(doc.document.get("id_here").toString().subSequence(1, doc.document.get("id_here").toString().length - 1).split(","))
```

```
 Also it may have extra spaces so don't forget to use the functions
```

`trimStart() && trimEnd()`

Comment: Try to optimize your answer to the target language of the question.