# Get ArrayList in Firestore - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an Android app that needs to access a document which has an ArrayList in it.

I took a look at this link [Check This Stack Overflow Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422552/getting-an-arraylist-from-firestore-and-the-document-name)

I tried everything I could. The guy even gave the answer that we should do `(ArrayList<String>) documentSnapshot.get("key")`. I tried doing that but when I do, I get this error from Android Studio: `Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>'`. It's also asking me to generify my class.

This is my Firestore structure.

[image: This is my Firestore structure.]

This is my code till now:

```
DocumentReference docRef = firestore.collection("Users").document(fullMobile);
                docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        assert document != null;
                        // Data from FireStore
                        ArrayList<String> devices = (ArrayList<String>) document.get("Devices"); ----- This is the line which is wrong.
                        if (document.exists()) { // LOGIN
                            // Some Code
                        } else { // SIGNUP
                           // Some Code
                        }
                    } else {
                        toast("An Error Occured! Please Try Again");
                    }
                });
```

I don't know what to do know. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Add some last part of code.

Comment: Please clarify your use of terminology.  No document in Firestore "is an ArrayList".  A document might **contain** an array.  It would be useful if you shared a description (or screenshot) of your Firestore structure, and then the exact code you are using to fetch document(s) from Firestore and extract the array data you are trying to load into the UI.

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747054/firebase-get-an-arraylist-field-from-all-documents) out. However, in your database, you have an array called "Sample", while in your code you are trying to get it as "Devices". Is that correct? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, the Array is Sample. You can ignore the "Devices" thing, I can change that later, and that is not the issue.

Comment: In that case, does androidLearner's answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your document contains array of data,Create arraylist then add item.

```
ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<>();
devices.add(document.get("Devices"));
```

If your document contains  custom object (model class), use same model class to get it back.

```
 for (DocumentSnapshot document : snapshots.getDocuments()) {
            String documentkey = document.getId();
             UsedCarDetailsModel usedCarDetailsModel = document.toObject(UsedCarDetailsModel.class);
             documentList.add(usedCarDetailsModel);

        }
```

If you are beginner, just place cursor on warning text then press Alt+Enter ,Android studio will show available option to cast your document. choose suitable one for you.

Comment: I am getting the same error that you should try to generify my class. Plus, the addAll() method only works for Collection, not for ArrayList.

Comment: try using this ArrayList<String> obj= document.toObject(ArrayList.class); @AnikethChavare

Comment: can you say how did you set  field in document.if you used List<> we can get it back as Arraylist.if you used custom class you need to use your custom class to get it back like  List<CustomClass>

Comment: this is the proper way to get document data when you use custom class CustomModelClass Model = document.toObject(CustomModelClass .class);